# Unwanted row space in TABLE

Tags: html, css, css-tables, cellpadding

I have a table which contains a segmented picture. Picture is segmented due to adding mouse over effect on some parts of picture.

Although the stand-alone version is OK, when integrated to WordPress as a side bar HTML code, becomes messy (`cell-padding` changes). Since I have no control over the parent control (here a `DIV`) how can I override parent CSS from my HTML code (without changing WordPress side-bar PHP code).

Answer (score 1):

There is a `line-height: 21px;` in your stylesheet. Remove that it looks good.

Comment: thanks. made it look better but not fixed. Is there a way in HTML to say don't inherit ant style in an object (here my table)? this would be more better than check every style-sheet.

Comment: I'm wondering why `line-height` influence a table with no text! Any other guess?

Comment: Yeah, still wondering. Was working on your issue for about an hour! Still no progress...

Answer (score 0):

You can use default css style such as

```
    table {
      margin-left:auto;
      .....
}
    td {
      margin-left:auto;
      .....  
}
    tr {
      margin-left:auto;
      .....
}
```